# ios7 with UIsearchBarController crashes?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, ios7, xcode5

I am woking on ios7.
In My app i am having UITableView and UISearchBar Controller.
while implementing UISearchBar Controller my application crashes
DUE TO following reason:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier listcell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'**

i am using custom UITabelViewCell.UISearchBarController delegate methods are also implemented.

Can any one provide me a better link or solution for this?

following is my code:

//----------------------code for search part------------------

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{ 
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF Contains[cd] %@",searchText];

    searchResults = [_detailList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;
}



-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [searchResults count];
    }
    else
    return _detailList.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"listcell";
//
   ListCell *listcell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


        listcell.lbl_detail.text = _detailList [indexPath.row];
    listcell.lbl_Address.text = _detailList1 [indexPath.row];
    listcell.lbl_link.text = _detailList2 [indexPath.row];
    listcell.lbl_number.text = _detailList3 [indexPath.row];


    return listcell;

}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
[(ContainerViewController *)self.parentViewController addDetailViewController];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to set the "listcell" identifier in the storyboard.

Comment: can u plz help me out with this issue

Comment: i have set that identifier in storyboard

Comment: @Nilesh, I have updated the answer. Please follow

Answer (score 0):

You should put the following line in the method viewDidLoad:

[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar registerClass:[ListCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"listcell"];