# custom cell in place of UIlabel what to do?

Tags: ios7

custom cell in place of UIlabel what can i do ? in method i want to used custom cell not the label. i want the custom cell and i am the new or fresher in ios so i did not know the more detail of custom cell , so please tell me how used custom cell in my code in place of label in tableview .

//  AppDelegate.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

  @class ViewController;

  @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

  @property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

  @property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

  -(void)copydb;

  @end
```

//  AppDelegate.m

```
  #import "AppDelegate.h"

  #import "ViewController.h"

  @implementation AppDelegate


  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
      self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]
  bounds]];
      // Override point for customization after application launch.
      self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]
  initWithNibName:@"ViewController"
  bundle:nil];
      self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

      [self copydb];

      return YES;
  }


  -(void)copydb
  {
      NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      NSString *documentdirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
      NSString *inspath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample.sqlite"];
      NSString *destpath=[documentdirectory
  stringByAppendingPathComponent:inspath];
      NSString *srcpath=[[[NSBundle
  mainBundle]resourcePath]stringByAppendingPathComponent:inspath];

      NSLog(@"\n srcpath= %@ \n destpath=%@",srcpath,destpath);

      if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:destpath])
      {
          NSError *error;
          NSLog(@"File not Exist");
          [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:srcpath
        toPath:destpath error:&error];
      }
      else
      {
          NSLog(@"File Exist");
      }
  }


   - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
  {
      // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive
        state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as
  an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the
      application and it begins the transition to the background state.
      // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle
        down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
  }

  - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
  {
      // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data,
  invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to
        restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated
  later.
      // If your application supports background execution, this method is
  called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
  }

  - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
  {
      // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive
  state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the
  background.
  }

  - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
  {
      // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the
  application was inactive. If the application was previously in the
        background, optionally refresh the user interface.
  }

  - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
  {
      // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if
  appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
  }
  @end
```

//vc.h

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  #import <sqlite3.h>
  @interface ViewController :
                               UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewD      elegate>
  {
IBOutlet UITextField *fnameTxt;
IBOutlet UITextField *lnameTxt;
IBOutlet UITextField *addressTxt;
IBOutlet UITextField *birthdateTxt;
IBOutlet UITextField *cityTxt;
IBOutlet UITableView *tbl;

sqlite3 *db;
NSMutableArray *data;
  }

  @property (atomic,retain)UILabel *label1;
  @property (atomic,retain)UILabel *label2;
  @property (atomic,retain)UILabel *label3;
  @property (atomic,retain)UILabel *label4;
  @property (atomic,retain)UILabel *label5;

  - (IBAction)submit:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)update:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)deletes:(id)sender;

  @end
```

//vc.m

```
  #import "ViewController.h"

  @interface ViewController ()

  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  @synthesize label1;
  @synthesize label2;
  @synthesize label3;
        @synthesize label4;
  @synthesize label5;

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      data=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

      [self load];

  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

  }

  -(void)load
  {

[fnameTxt resignFirstResponder];
[lnameTxt resignFirstResponder];
[addressTxt resignFirstResponder];
[birthdateTxt resignFirstResponder];
[cityTxt resignFirstResponder];

fnameTxt.text=@"";
lnameTxt.text=@"";
addressTxt.text=@"";
birthdateTxt.text=@"";
cityTxt.text=@"";

[data removeAllObjects];

NSString *insertstatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from
  emps"];
NSLog(@"%@",insertstatement);
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
NSString *path=[self getDBPath];
NSLog(@"%@",path);

if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
      {
   // if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [insertstatement UTF8String], -1,
  &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, [insertstatement UTF8String], -1,
  &statement, NULL)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *record=[[NSMutableDictionary
  alloc]init];

            NSString *fnm=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char
  *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            NSString *lnm=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char
  *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            NSString *addr=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char
  *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            NSString *bDay=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char
  *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
            NSString *cty=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char
  *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];

            [record setValue:fnm forKey:@"fName"];

            [record setValue:lnm forKey:@"lName"];

            [record setValue:addr forKey:@"adds"];

            [record setValue:bDay forKey:@"birthDay"];

            [record setValue:cty forKey:@"city"];

            [data addObject:record];

        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
      }
      NSLog(@"Number of data in Array is = %d",[data count]);
      [tbl reloadData];

  }


  - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
  {
[fnameTxt resignFirstResponder];
[lnameTxt resignFirstResponder];
[addressTxt resignFirstResponder];
[birthdateTxt resignFirstResponder];
[cityTxt resignFirstResponder];

return YES;
  }


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  {
return 1;
  }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
 return [data count];
  }





      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
       cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
         {
        static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView
         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

       if (cell==nil)
      {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell
    alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
         reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    //my added new code

    label1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 3, 100, 40)];
    label1.tag=1;
    label1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 20.0];
    label1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    label1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];

    label2 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 3, 100, 40)];
    label2.tag=2;
    label2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 20.0];
    label2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
       UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label2.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label2];


    label3 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(155, 3, 80, 40)];
    label3.tag=3;
    label3.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 20.0];
    label3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    label3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label3.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label3];


    label4 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230, 3, 100, 40)];
    label4.tag=4;
    label4.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 20.0];
    label4.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    label4.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label4.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label4];


    label5= [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 3, 120, 40)];
    label5.tag=5;
    label5.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 20.0];
    label5.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    label5.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    label5.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label5];

    }
    else
    {
    label1 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    label2 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    label3 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3];
    label4 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:4];
    label5 = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:5];

    }


    label1.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"fName"];
    label2.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"lName"];
    label3.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"adds"];
    label4.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"birthDay"];
     label5.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"city"];
   /*
    [cell addSubview:label1];
    [cell addSubview:label2];
    [cell addSubview:label3];
     [cell addSubview:label4];
    [cell addSubview:label5];
    */


   /*    [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:label2];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:label3];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label4];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label5];
    */


      /*   cell.textLabel.text=[[data
  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"fName"];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[data
  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"lName"];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[data
        objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"adds"];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[data
  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"birthDay"];
 cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[data
  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"city"];
 */
return cell;

  }

  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
fnameTxt.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"fName"];
lnameTxt.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"lName"];
addressTxt.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@
  "adds"];
birthdateTxt.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@
  "birthDay"];
cityTxt.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"city"];

  }


  - (IBAction)submit:(id)sender
  {
      if([fnameTxt.text isEqualToString:@""] || [lnameTxt.text
  isEqualToString:@""] || [addressTxt.text isEqualToString:@""] ||
  [birthdateTxt.text isEqualToString:@""] || [cityTxt.text isEqualToString:@
  ""])
      {
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SORRY ERROR
  !!!" message:@"Please Don't leaves any blanlk detail...." delegate:nil
  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
      }
      else
      {

    NSString *path=[self getDBPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",path);
    NSString *insertstatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into
  emps (fName,lName,adds,birthDay,city) values
              ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",fnameTxt.text,lnameTxt.text,addressTxt.text,birthdateTxt.text,cityTxt.text];

          NSLog(@"%@",insertstatement);

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //        char *errMsg;
       //        const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS imageTbl (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, imagestr TEXT)";
      //        
      //        if (sqlite3_exec(db, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
      //        {
      //            //status.text = @"Failed to create table";
      //            NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
      //        }
      //        else
      //        {
      //            NSLog(@"create table Successfully");
      //        }
        const char *sql=[insertstatement UTF8String];
        char *err;

        if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &err)!=SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in insert !!!");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Insert perform successfully!!!");
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView
  alloc]initWithTitle:@"Submited..."
  message:@"Record submited successfully....." delegate:nil
  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    else
    {
    }
    [self load];
    /*
     *** code for display the textbox data into alert view ***
     UIAlertView *aler=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"user
  Information" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"First Name :%@ \n Last
  Name :%@ \n Address :%@ \n BirthDate :%@ \n City : %@",fnameTxt.text ,
  lnameTxt.text ,addressTxt.text , birthdateTxt.text , cityTxt.text ]
   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

     [aler show];
     */
            }
  }

  - (IBAction)update:(id)sender
  {
      NSString *path=[self getDBPath];

      NSString *insertstatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"update emps set
  fName='%@',lName='%@',adds='%@',birthDay='%@',city='%@' where
  birthDay='%@'"
  ,fnameTxt.text,lnameTxt.text,addressTxt.text,birthdateTxt.text,cityTxt.text,birthdateTxt.te      xt];

      NSLog(@"%@",insertstatement);

      if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
      {
    const char *sql=[insertstatement UTF8String];
    char *err;

    if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &err)!=SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error in Update !!!");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Update perform successfully!!!");
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Update..."
  message:@"Record Updated successfully....." delegate:nil
        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
        otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);
      }
      else
      {
      }
      [self load];

  }

        - (IBAction)deletes:(id)sender
  {
      UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Are
  you sure to DELETE this record ???" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];

      /*
       ***this code written into alert OK button click event ***

       NSString *path=[self getDBPath];

       NSString *insertstatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" delete from
         emp  where birthDay='%@' " , birthdateTxt.text];

       NSLog(@"%@",insertstatement);

       if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
       {
       const char *sql=[insertstatement UTF8String];
       char *err;

 if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &err)!=SQLITE_OK)
 {
 NSLog(@"Error in Delete !!!");
 }
 else
 {
 NSLog(@"Delete perform successfully!!!");
 UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Delete..."
  message:@"Record Deleted successfully....." delegate:nil
  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
 [alert show];
 }
 sqlite3_close(db);
 }
 else
 {
 }
 [self load];

 */
  }


  // *** code for alertview button click ***

  - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
  clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  {
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{

}
if (buttonIndex == 1)
{
    NSString *path=[self getDBPath];

    NSString *insertstatement=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" delete from
    emps  where birthDay='%@' " , birthdateTxt.text];

    NSLog(@"%@",insertstatement);

    if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &db)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql=[insertstatement UTF8String];
        char *err;

        if(sqlite3_exec(db, sql, NULL, NULL, &err)!=SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in Delete !!!");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Delete perform successfully!!!");
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView
  alloc]initWithTitle:@"Delete..."
  message:@"Record Deleted successfully....." delegate:nil
  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    else
    {
    }
    [self load];

      }

  }


  -(NSString *)getDBPath
  {
NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentdirectory=[paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *inspath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sample.sqlite"];
NSString *destpath=[documentdirectory
  stringByAppendingPathComponent:inspath];

return destpath;
  }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
  @end
```

please see my above code ,just tell me about custom cell ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your table view method of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You need to replace this code with your custom `uitableviewcell` class. And then inside this you need to create nib file and load inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

//Comment this code

```
 //   UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

//Modify the same above code with below mentioned link code.

Refer [CustomUiTableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046967/ios7-with-uisearchbarcontroller-crashes/21047050#21047050)

Answer (score 0):

You say "... custom cell in place of UIlabel what can i do?"

It is not at all clear what you are asking. Table view cells only live inside a table view, and a table view cannot contain a UILabel in place of a table view cell. They are never interchangeable.

You posted lots and lots of code, most of it standard boiler-plate code. I waded through it all (which was annoying...)

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method you are creating a standard UITableViewCell and adding 5 UILabels to it. It looks to me like the labels are too big to fit in a cell, but that's secondary.

What are you trying to do, create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell that contains labels as IBOutlets, and instantiate custom cells rather than standard cells?

Please make a clear statement of what you are trying to do.

Also, you need to tell us if you're using storyboards or XIB files, and if you are using a UITableViewController or a standard view controller.